# View Source link does not work in Live Visual Tree, Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2017

Environment:

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2017
- .NET Framework 4.6.2 Targeted

Pre-reqs:
Enable Runtime Tools. Disable managed compatibility mode. Create WPF project, mine includes custom dialogs and buttons (I don't think this matters though).

Steps:

- 1. Start build in Debug mode
  2. Select "Enable Selection" from the runtime tools box.
  3. Select a control on the GUI.
  4. Select "Go to Live Visual Tree"

     - The selected control is identified in the Live Visual Tree.
  5. Right click control.

     - View Source option is listed, available, and clickable.
  6. Click "View Source".

     - ISSUE: Nothing happens, file is not shown.
  7. Right click the control again, select "Show Properties"
  8. Under Live Property Explorer, next to the "Local" drop down is the file where the control is referenced, it is a clickable link
     "testwindow.xaml". Click the link to the file (should be the same as
     the "View Source" button).

     - ISSUE: Nothing happens, file is not shown.

From here I can search the Solution Explorer and manually open the file.

What might prevent the "View Source" button from opening the file?

[image: view source button]

Comment: Which exact Visual Studio. Same problem here, but I don't understand the 'clickable link' - or maybe it's just not there for UserControls? I'm using VS 2017 15.8 Preview 3 currently

Comment: Currently using VS Pro 2017, Ver. 15.7.2. The clickable link should be available for UserControls. I've noticed sometimes it is doesn't display, mainly if I attached a program to the debugger after running. My current theory to this issue is just that my repo is too large (~11GB) to run this feature.